# Start fish shell in vi insert mode?

Tags: fish

Using `fish_vi_key_bindings`, fish shell starts in `normal` mode. How can I change the default start to `insert` mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fish_vi_key_bindings` takes an argument to indicate the initial mode.

That means `fish_vi_key_bindings insert` will do what you want.